# How to change badge number in bottom navigation of main activity from fragment?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, badge

I want to change or set  badge number from fragment but i have no idea how to do it
here is my code :-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_nav_bar);

toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_white));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


navigationView = findViewById(R.id.mynavigation);
drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.mydrawer);
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.my_bottom_menu);
badgeDrawable = bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.cart);

badgeDrawable.setNumber(0);


bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
```

}

Comment: have you tried adding "badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);" to your code?

Comment: i tried but it didn't worked

Answer (score 2):

Call this method from fragment

```
MyActivity myAct= (MyActivity) getActivity();
myAct.increaseCount(4);
```

In MyActivity.java add this method

```
 public void increaseCount(int count){
    badgeDrawable.setNumber(count);
}
```